# Is self-selection for a treatment a problem after all?

Tags: inference, least-squares, causality, selection-bias

I have devised the following R code.

In this simulated dataset, we know that a certain treatment (e.g. a degree, an education) increases income by $ 1,000. Income is also caused by age.

In the first part, units are randomly assigned into treatment. Each unit has a 50% probability to receive the treatment, regardless of his/her age.

In the second part, subjects self-select into treatment: younger units have a higher probability to receive treatment than older ones. We can check that the units that receive treatment are younger: we do a boxplot, and a t-test rejects the null hypothesis that the average age is the same across the treated and non treated groups.

By running an OLS, I am able to estimate the effect of treatment on income in both cases, so also in the second case where people self-select themselves into treatment.

In the second part, can I infer from the OLS that the treatment causes an increase in income by $ 1,000?

Is self-selection a problem for that inference?

````r
N = 100000
age_coeff = 100
treated_coeff = 1000

# PART 1: RANDOM SELECTION INTO TREATMENT
df = data.frame(id=seq(from=1, to=N, by=1))
df$age = runif(N, min=0, max=100)
# size -> number of trials (zero or more)
df$treated = rbinom(N, size=1, prob=0.5)
df$treated = df$treated==1
e = rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=50)

# Check age is the same across the two groups
r <- aggregate(df$age, list(df$treated), FUN=mean) 
colnames(r) <- c("Treated", "Age")
print(r)
t.test(df$age[df$treated], df$age[!df$treated])

df$income = 0 + age_coeff*df$age + treated_coeff*df$treated + e
income.lm = lm(income~age+treated, data=df)
summary(income.lm)

# PART 2: SELF-SELECTION INTO TREATMENT
library(sigmoid)
df$ptreated = logistic(50-df$age)
df$treated = rbinom(N, size=1, prob=df$ptreated)
df$treated = df$treated==1

# Check if selection into treatment is effective
boxplot(df$ptreated~df$treated)
r <- aggregate(df$ptreated, list(df$treated), FUN=mean) 
colnames(r) <- c("Treated", "p(Treated)")
print(r)

# Check if age differs in the two groups
r <- aggregate(df$age, list(df$treated), FUN=mean) 
colnames(r) <- c("Treated", "Age")
print(r)
boxplot(df$age~df$treated)
t.test(df$age[df$treated], df$age[!df$treated])

df$income = 0 + age_coeff*df$age + treated_coeff*df$treated + e
income.lm = lm(income~age+treated, data=df)
summary(income.lm)

# Check
df$age50 <- df$age >= 50
table(df$age50, df$treated, dnn=c("Age50", "treated"))
```
````

Comment: It's no problem if you don't care about drawing valid inferences about the treatment!  But in what sense is this an "econometrics estimate"?

Comment: @whuber The coefficient I obtain in the second part (where subjects self-select into treat) is correct. I'm changing the last question with the following: In the second part, can I infer that treat increases outcome by 1000?

Comment: Your code does not run: what is `age_coeff` ?

Comment: But the problem in reality with self-selection is that not only can factors you know about affect self-selection (age here), but so can factors you do not know about and cannot control for

Comment: @Henry I have modified the code to make the selection even less deterministic. `age_coeff` is the effect of age on income and is defined at the beginning of the code

Comment: @Henry If I know _all_ the factors that determine both selection into treatment and outcome (they are confounders of treatment and outcome, as `age` is in this case), and I can measure them with _no_ measurement error, and I put them into my OLS estimates as covariates, the coefficient I obtain for the treatment variable is the causal effect of the treatment on the outcome, right?

Comment: @robertspierre I cannot image scenario where you would know them “all” and there would be no measurement error at all, also regression analysis has nothing to do with causality. So are you asking about real data, or this is a completely theoretical question assuming a hypothetical scenario?

Comment: @Tim I guess my question would be: in what cases self-selection into treatment is a problem for the estimation of the causal effect?

Comment: I'm unclear if the dependent variable here is a given treatment outcome, or simply if they opted for treatment or not.

Comment: @GreggH I would be interested in the answer for both cases: when we assign treatment to younger persons, and when younger persons self-select into treatment. I have also modified the text of the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

1. A t-test doesn't construct a certainty interval around the actual treatment difference, even the CI can't be interpreted that way. No NHST method will tell you the actual treated difference is 1000. However, both models should be powered to reject the null hypothesis that income does not differ by treatment assignment.
2. In the self-selection scenario, age is a confounder. But in your inference you have adjusted for age to eliminate confounding. Therefore, the linear model is expected to adjust the counfounding effects. The model is not a t-test but an adjusted linear model. Had you used the t-test the result would be biased.
3. In practice the issue doesn't boil down to known confounders with known functional forms, but unknown confounders with unknown functional forms. You are often presented with data that failed to collect certain values, or at the appropriate times, or with desired precision, subject to recall bias, reverse confounding, non-ignorable missingness. The methods for handling these cases when the precise mechanism is known is almost irrelevant, but understanding how to assess a data analysis and put together results from multiple studies and ascertain the impact of confounding is a subtler and more valuable art.

Comment: I don't understand (1) and (2). I used a t-test ONLY to check whether the mean age is different across the treated and non treated groups. I used the t test to check that the distribution of the confounder is different between the treated and not treated group. I did NOT use a t-test to assess the treatment difference, the difference in the outcome (which is income in the example) between treated and not treated), I used an OLS model for that. I understand (3) instead. Thanks

Comment: @robertspierre in your own words, "In the second part, can I infer that treatment increases outcome by 1000?" and to that the answer is no. For 2, admittedly I was confused what your outcome was here. In general you do not test for confounding. You can't distinguish a variable as a collider, confounder, or mediator by tests: a variable is identified as a confounder a priori - you don't test for it.

Comment: Yes the text was not very clear. The answer to my question is "no" due to reason (3)? There may be other confounders I don't observe, or reverse causality bias? I was not trying to control if the variable is a confounder. Given that I hypothesize a priori the variable is a confounder, I was trying to check whether it is randomized across treatment vs non treated group

Comment: I have modified the text of the question to make it clearer. If your (3) is the answer I will accept it